# Binary search for specific value in array of structs

Tags: struct, binary-search

I wrote this function that uses a binary search to look for a specific value in an array of structs. Why doesn't it compile?

I'm getting this error:

> ```
> prog.c:224: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
> prog.c:226: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer
> ```

This is the function:

```
int FieldSearch(Field *pArr, int size, int val)
{
    int low=0,high=size-1, middle;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        middle = (low + high)/2;
        if (val == pArr->Id[middle])
            return middle;
        else if (val < pArr->Id[middle])
            high = middle -1;
        else
            low = middle +1;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

This is the field struct:

```
typedef struct field
{
        char Id;
        Coordinates location;
        int area;
        int price;
} Field;
```

Maybe the prototype is wrong...

Comment: id is integer i mean %d, yes this is c...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search the "array" pArr, you need to put the brackets directly behind the identitifier. This should work:

```
pArr[middle].Id
```

Comment: ok that seem to work..  i guess that problem was that i didn't put the brackets at right place..this is the fix line                                                                             if (val == pArr[middle].Id)    
       return middle;     
  else if (val < pArr[middle].Id)                               thnx guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this statement:

```
pArr->Id[middle]
```

It looks like, but I don't have nearly enough info, that your member Id is not a pointer or an array, but merely a variable.  So you cannot access it with an `operator[]`.  You should show us what this `Field` object looks like.

I'm guessing you should do something like this

`(pArr + middle)->Id` so this will access the element of the Field array you passed into your function.  Then you do have to pass in an actual array of `Field` structures, for this to work.

Comment: this is the field struct:                                        typedef struct field 
{
        char Id;
        Coordinates location;
        int area;
        int price;
} Field;

Comment: Id is not an array, you cannot access it with the `operator[]`, as I said